# Can't find beta test link for Google play testers?

Tags: android, google-play, beta

Ok, I am new to beta/alpha testing with Google play and I recently uploaded my apk and published to Google play alpha testing. Ive followed all Google's documentation however my testers have not received any emails like iTunes Connect does, and they cannot see the app in Google Play.

My understanding was that they/I would be given a link in google play and would be able to download the app. I have added my testers here, but there is no link:[image]

Then in app releases I have this:

[image]

but when I click on edit I don't see a link there either. How can I beta/alpha test in Google play?

Now:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Expand the "Manage testers" using the button at the right hand corner in the  "edit app release page". (The last screenshot on your post)

You will see the opt-in-url in there.

Similar to the screen shown by Lahiru Chandima.

Answer (score 0):

When you created the beta release, you should get a page like following.

[image]

You should send the `Opt-in URL` to testers, so they can accept to test your app. When they accept, a link will be given to them with the play store URL of your app.

Comment: I think I had that initially but the url was not filled it it said something like "Fill in url later", it was not a url. I can't access that page now I posted what I see when I go to alpha

Comment: @skyguy what happens when you click on `Manage testers` section (below `Create Release` button)?

Comment: I can't click on it- its just there. Not clickable